# What's the differences between a Resolver and a Synchro?

Tags: synchro

I understand a Resolver is a kind of Synchro, and a Synchro has 3 windings, 120 degrees phased from each other, while a Resolver has only 2, 90 degrees phased.

Both of them are used in agle measurement of a shaft, but it's not clear to me when to use one or the other and what are the benefits of each of them and disadvantages?

I can find lots of information about [Resolvers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolver_%28electrical%29) and [Synchros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchro) but I couldn't find any relating the two of them. A good example for resolvers applications and operation can be find [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCU8b8vo2qE)

As you can see in the documentations, Synchros can be used to track motion between two safts using jut 2 synchros...so if they are so "cool" why do people bother to use resolvers? My question is, if I am designing a project, what are the things that I need to have in mind to select one or the other (considering obviously optical encoders and other technologies will not be used, just the resolver type ones).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't show any effort.

Comment: What "effort" has anything to do with "topic"?

Comment: @mFeinstein I've had a go at an answer but I agree about providing more information and also you shouldn't quibble about it being off-topic - lack of research does qualify as "off-topic" but I've kind of answered because I'm interested in a better answer to this.

Comment: @Andyaka I added some information about them

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you about synchronous resolvers because I was trained on them in my apprenticeship.

A synchronous-resolver is probably what you refer to as a "synchro" and like you say, it has three windings (on the stator) and also a rotor winding brought out on slip rings. They are just like a synchronous motor or generator used in industry but way smaller. There use was in encoding (as you also said) but they had a great little feature in that if you wired two units back to back i.e. all the stator windings coupled back to back and ditto the rotor windings, you could apply a single phase AC voltage to both rotors (via the slip rings) and if you physically rotated one unit, the other unit would track the physical movement. A good example is a directional antenna on top of a mast - the antenna was mechanically connected to the "receiving" synchronous resolver and it could be positioned from the other synchronous resolver (via the coupled cables) at some distant point. The accuracy appeared to be phenomenal and that's not a surprise given the cost of them.

Now here's where it gets a little sticky (mainly due to my memory); the other type of unit which you refer to as a resolver is two stator coils at 90 degrees (like you said) but I don't believe it can be used in the above example.

**EDIT** - this section is incorrect but I've left it in so that I can be justifiably ridiculed and tormented by my error. From memory it can do a 360 degree determination of angle but at the neutral point of the rotor (halfway between stator coils, 45 degrees) it can be flipped 180 degrees and you wouldn't know the difference. OK, end of **edit**.

I'm not going to say on more on this because I think you should do some research (like is being hinted in the comments) and come up with a couple of examples of units that you can buy and that have data sheets so that they can be further analysed. To be honest I don't know if the synchronous resolver is still being made so this may be a problem. All the ones I saw were pre 1970s units taken off military vessels.

A fascinating read: [synchros and resolvers](http://www.moog.com/literature/MCG/synchrohbook.pdf): -

[image]

Comment: +1 There's a nice demonstration of the three-winding type here http://youtu.be/fcoR8plMMK8?t=14m37s

Comment: @ChrisJohnson - very cool demo!!

Comment: @Andyaka I made some research before asking, I just didn't pointed it out, I found everything you said about the 2 units, I just can't find why to use one or the other. Also I believe your point on resolvers is a little wrong. They can measure 360 degrees, using a sine and a cosine output, there will be 4 "ranges" where they both flip in phase and amplitude with the signal powering the device so this way you can measure it all. I added some examples in my question

Comment: @mFeinstein I agree with you dude. My answer about resolvers is wrong. I've just read the links you posted. I think that maybe they can't easily be used as I described the synchro. Maybe? Hopefully better answers will emerge but I'll edit mine to reflect what you unconvered.

Comment: @Andyaka yes, I agree resolvers probably cant be used to track motion as synchors can, but my question is basically why to use one instead of the other? I mean, if sychros are so cool, what makes people use resolvers?

Comment: @mFeinstein resolvers don't have to have slip rings - the rotor is like an induction motor i.e. it is a shorted turn - it receives energy by induction for a primary winding that always couples to the rotor. The two quad windings are the outputs. Maybe this is the real deal - a contactless rotor?

Comment: @Andyaka I am aware they can be brushed and brushless...but cant synchros also be both brushed an brushless?

Comment: @mFeinstein I'd say not because that would add another error in the alignment and both rotors need to be fed the same phase of signal. Maybe some are but they won't be as accurate maybe?

Comment: @Andyaka I dont know, I found many brushless resolvers and synchros...in page 2-5 of the document you provided I can conclude brushless synchros are more complex, but I am not 100% sure

Comment: @mFeinstein Time to be patient maybe and hope for a better answer.

Comment: @Andyaka I guess so :)

Comment: @mFeinstein Hope it's not a homework question LOL

Comment: @Andyaka hahaha no no, fortunately I just graduated :D!

Comment: The point in the Moog document is that you can use the resolver to do trig coordinate transformations.. Presumably from the gimbals of a gyro platform back in the days before strap-down navigation. Make sense?

Comment: Resolvers are still used, they are very good for bad environments and high vibration systems

Comment: Another handbook : http://www.ddc-web.com/Documents/synhdbk.pdf

Answer (score -1):

The biggest difference between synchros and resolvers is their construction difference.

They both have a single-winding rotor. 
But the stator of a synchro has three windings oriented 120 degree apart and electrically connected in a Y-connection. 
The stator of a resolver differs from a synchro in that its stator has two windings oriented in 90 degree.

Comment: My guess would be, the synchro could be slightly more accurate and linear as data is polled from six vectors instead of four. This may also mean more computation per-revolution as rotor speeds increase. (I have no idea how some Mitsubishi servo motors have 131k pulses per revolution at 3k RPM yet maintain absolute accuracy...)